# R apply returning rows but want columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to clean survey data where sometimes minutes information is entered in the hours field. The cleaning rules say to move the hours value to the minutes field if mins is missing or 0 and hours is 15 or 30 or 45 or 60.

Here is the function I wrote:

```
cleanHrMin <- function(x){
  h = x[1]
  m = x[2]
  if ( !is.na(h) && (h==15 || h==30 || h==45 || h==60) && (m==0 || is.na(m)) )
    { return(c(0,h)) }
  else
    { return(x) }
}
```

With test data:

```
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(hrs = c(1,15,0), mins = c(10,NA,15)))
```

I run the function as follows:

```
as.data.frame(apply(df,1,cleanHrMin))
```

and get output:

```
  V1 V2 V3
1  1  0  0
2 10 15 15
```

But what I want is:

```
  V1 V2
1  1 10
2  0 15
3  0 15
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing the correct apply, across rows.  You simply need to transpose the output.

```
> as.data.frame(t(apply(df,1,cleanHrMin)))
  V1 V2
1  1 10
2  0 15
3  0 15
```

This is because `apply` returns columns resulting from the function, whether your margin is over rows or over columns.  So to go from rows to rows, you must transpose.